# Turning off text to speech in iMessage

Tags: macos, messages

How can I turn off the "text to speech" feature in iMessage?  I don't mind iMessage bouncing in the dock when a message comes in, but I can't have iMessage speaking the message.  Not only is this feature distracting, but sometimes a message is private and I don't want anyone within earshot hearing my text "conversations"...I'm running OS X Version 10.8.4

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

[image]

Uncheck "Speak an announcement".